# Using R, how can I make columns become rows and correlate with values of another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-wrangling

Basically I need a new column called "census" containing columns dbh1, dbh3, and dbh4 as sequential rows, correlating with their tree number and species of interest.

The data looks like this (with 10k rows):

| Tree | Spec | dbh1 | dbh3 | dbh4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PICO | 6 | 8.8 | 9 |
| 2 | ABLA | 21 | 24.1 | 25.4 |
| 3 | PICO | 12 | 14.3 | 15.2 |
| 4 | PIEN | 24 | 25.5 | 25.8 |

I need it to look like this:

| Tree | Spec | Census |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PICO | 6 |
| 1 | PICO | 8.8 |
| 1 | PICO | 9 |
| 2 | ABLA | 21 |
| 2 | ABLA | 24.1 |
| 2 | ABLA | 25.4 |
| 3 | PICO | 12 |
| 3 | PICO | 14.3 |
| 3 | PICO | 15.2 |
| 4 | PIEN | 24 |
| 4 | PIEN | 25.5 |
| 4 | PIEN | 25.8 |

I've tried looking around the tidyverse and I'm sure I'm missing what could be a very simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer()` from `tidyr` to pivot your dataframe, and then remove the new column with the information of which original variable the values from Census came from.

#### Data

```
df <-
  structure(list(Tree = 1:4, Spec = c("PICO", "ABLA", "PICO", "PIEN"
  ), dbh1 = c(6L, 21L, 12L, 24L), dbh3 = c(8.8, 24.1, 14.3, 25.5
  ), dbh4 = c(9, 25.4, 15.2, 25.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```

#### Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("dbh"),values_to = "Census") %>% 
  select(-name)
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
    Tree Spec  Census
   <int> <chr>  <dbl>
 1     1 PICO     6  
 2     1 PICO     8.8
 3     1 PICO     9  
 4     2 ABLA    21  
 5     2 ABLA    24.1
 6     2 ABLA    25.4
 7     3 PICO    12  
 8     3 PICO    14.3
 9     3 PICO    15.2
10     4 PIEN    24  
11     4 PIEN    25.5
12     4 PIEN    25.8
```